# Using \ifthenelse inside tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I'm trying to draw a simple plot of certain line I need, and I've used a conditional to generalize every case.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}        

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{my style1/.append style={clip = false, axis lines* = middle, axis equal, xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, fpu} 

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{4=3}{hi}{bye}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
        \lra = 1;
        \lrb = -3;
        \dor = 0;
        \ifthenelse{\lra = 0}{\dor = 4/\lrb}{\dor = 4/\lra};
    }   
    \begin{axis}[my style1, samples=200]
        \addplot [red, domain=-\dor:\dor] ({x*\lra},{x*\lrb});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

    
\end{document}
```

But I'm getting the error "Argument of \ifthenelse has an extra }". I can't understand why. Using \ifthenelse in normal text, it worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: \ifthenelse is not expandable. You can't use it in such calculations.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `\tikzmath` has its own `if ... then ... else` construct. Why are you trying to use `\ifthenlese` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ifthenelse` function. With a slight complication, because both expressions in the true and false branches are evaluated and you can't divide by zero.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, fpu}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  \lra = 1;
  \lrb = -3;
  \dor = ifthenelse(\lra == 0, 4/\lrb, 4/(or(\lra,1)*\lra));
}
\show\dor

\tikzmath{
  \lra = 0;
  \lrb = -3;
  \dor = ifthenelse(\lra == 0, 4/\lrb, 4/(or(\lra,1)*\lra));
}
\show\dor

\end{document}
```

```
> \dor=macro:
->4.0.
l.13 \show\dor

?
> \dor=macro:
->-1.33333.
l.20 \show\dor
```

The `or` function keeps PGF happy in the second case when it would otherwise try division by zero.

Comment: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1006 Probaly hard to fix, because it looks like it's the parser that is evaluating eagerly.

Comment: @HenriMenke Also `\fp_eval:n` has the conditional, and for technical reasons it evaluates all the involved expressions. It’s just important to warn about it.